# Drawing a circle in directx 9

Tags: c++, directx, graphics2d

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to draw a circle in directx. I'm able to draw a triangle, so I imagined that I might be able to draw one by just rotating a triangle in a circle. However, I'm absolutely stumped. I've been scouring the net for hours with no luck. Can anyone help me out? Here's my code:

Main.cpp

```
#include "Engine.h"
#include "Box2D.h"
#include "Triangle2D.h"

class MyApp : public Engine {
public:

    Box2D box2D;
    Triangle2D triangle2D;

    void OnStartup() override {
        box2D.New(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff)); 
        triangle2D.New(150.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
    }

    void OnShutdown() override {
        box2D.Delete();
        triangle2D.Delete();
    }

    void OnDraw() override {
        box2D.Draw();
        triangle2D.Draw();
    }

    void OnMouseDown(int x, int y) {
        Debug("%d %d\n", x, y);
    }

};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    MyApp app;
    app.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

Engine.cpp

```
#include "Engine.h"

// Initialize the classes static variables
Engine* Engine::_ENGINE = NULL;

// Returns the current instance of this class
Engine* Engine::GetInstance()
{
    return _ENGINE;
}

// Constructor
Engine::Engine()
: _exit(false)
, _window(NULL)
, _directx(NULL)
, _device(NULL)
{
    _ENGINE = this;
}

// Deconstructor
Engine::~Engine() {
    _ENGINE = NULL;
}

// Run the core main event loop, start to finish
bool Engine::Run() {

    // Create the Windows class
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS | CS_CLASSDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = _WND_PROC;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszClassName = _GetModuleName();
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Adjust the window rect for the flags
    RECT rect;
    SetRect(&rect, 0, 0, _WIDTH, _HEIGHT);
    const DWORD windowFlags = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, windowFlags, FALSE, 0);

    // Create the window
    _window = CreateWindowEx(0, _GetModuleName(), _GetModuleName(), windowFlags, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (_window == NULL)
        return false;

    // Move the window to the center of the screen
    RECT system;
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &system, 0);
    MoveWindow(_window, (system.right - system.left) / 2 - (rect.right - rect.left) / 2, (system.bottom - system.top) / 2 - (rect.bottom - rect.top) / 2, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, TRUE);

    // Startup Direct X
    if (_DirectXStartup() == false)
        return false;

    // Call our startup callback
    OnStartup();

    // Show the window
    ShowWindow(_window, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    // Run the event loop
    MSG msg;
    ULONGLONG timer = GetTickCount64();
    while (!_exit) {

        // Handle normal system events
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        // Run the timer at the framerate
        if (timer + 1000 / _FPS < GetTickCount64()) {
            timer = GetTickCount64();

            // Clear the buffer
            _device->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0x00, 0xff, 0x00), 1.0f, NULL);

            // Call our draw callback every frame
            OnDraw();

            // Render to screen
            _device->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }

    }

    // Hide the window to avoid flicker
    ShowWindow(_window, SW_HIDE);

    // Call our shutdown callback
    OnShutdown();

    // Shutdown Direct X
    _DirectXShutdown();

    // Cleanup and destroy the window
    DestroyWindow(_window);
    UnregisterClass(_GetModuleName(), GetModuleHandle(NULL));

    return true;
}

// Return the DirectX device, needed by other DirectX objects
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 Engine::GetDevice() {
    return _device;
}

// Return our width
int Engine::GetWidth() {
    return _WIDTH;
}

// Return our height
int Engine::GetHeight() {
    return _HEIGHT;
}

// Our own custom debug string
void Engine::Debug(const char* message, ...) {
#if _DEBUG
    if (message) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, message);
        int size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, message, args);
        if (size > 0) {
            char* string = new char[size + 1];
            vsnprintf(string, size + 1, message, args);
            OutputDebugStringA(string);
            delete[] string;
        }
        va_end(args);
    }
#endif
}

// This is the Windows callback
LRESULT CALLBACK Engine::_WND_PROC(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    // If we do not have access to an instance of our engine, do nothing
    if (Engine::_ENGINE == NULL)
        return  DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    // Handle system messages
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        Engine::_ENGINE->OnMouseDown(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));
        return 0;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        if ((lParam & (1 << 30)) == 0)
            Engine::_ENGINE->OnKeyDown((int)wParam);
        return 0;
    case WM_CHAR:
        if ((int)wParam <= 127 && isprint((int)wParam) && (lParam & (1 << 30)) == 0)
            Engine::_ENGINE->OnASCIIDown((char)wParam);
        return 0;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        Engine::_ENGINE->_exit = true;
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

// Custom function for getting our exe name
WCHAR* Engine::_GetModuleName() {
    static WCHAR* TITLE = NULL;
    static WCHAR BUFFER[MAX_PATH];
    if (TITLE != NULL)
        return TITLE;

    // Remove the path
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, BUFFER, MAX_PATH);
    TITLE = wcsrchr(BUFFER, '\\');
    if (TITLE == NULL) {
        wcscpy(BUFFER, L"Application");
        TITLE = BUFFER;
        return TITLE;
    }
    TITLE++;

    // Remove the extension
    WCHAR* ext = wcsrchr(BUFFER, '.');
    if (ext)
        *ext = 0;

    return TITLE;
}

// Startup DirectX here
bool Engine::_DirectXStartup() {

    // Startup Direct X
    _directx = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    if (_directx == NULL)
        return false;

    // Create a Direct X device
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = _window;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = _WIDTH;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = _HEIGHT;
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D24X8;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;
    HRESULT result = _directx->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, _window, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &_device);
    if (FAILED(result))
        result = _directx->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_REF, _window, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &_device);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    return true;
}

// Shutdown DirectX here
bool Engine::_DirectXShutdown() {
    if (_device) {
        _device->Release();
        _device = NULL;
    }
    if (_directx) {
        _directx->Release();
        _directx = NULL;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Engine.h

```
#ifndef _ENGINE_H_
#define _ENGINE_H_

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

class Engine {
public:
    // Return the current singleton of this Engine class
    static Engine* GetInstance();

    // Constructor and deconstructor
    Engine();
    virtual ~Engine();

    // Run the Engine class
    bool Run();

    // Return useful information about the class
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 GetDevice();
    int GetWidth();
    int GetHeight();

    // Use for debug output
    static void Debug(const char* message, ...);

    // Virtual callbacks
    virtual void OnStartup() {}
    virtual void OnShutdown() {}
    virtual void OnMouseDown(int x, int y) {}
    virtual void OnKeyDown(int key) {}
    virtual void OnASCIIDown(char key) {}
    virtual void OnDraw() {}

private:
    static Engine* _ENGINE;
    static const int _WIDTH = 854;
    static const int _HEIGHT = 480;
    static const int _FPS = 60;
    bool _exit;
    HWND _window;
    LPDIRECT3D9 _directx;
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 _device;

    static LRESULT CALLBACK _WND_PROC(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    WCHAR* _GetModuleName();
    bool _DirectXStartup();
    bool _DirectXShutdown();
};

#endif // _ENGINE_H_
```

Triangle2D.h

```
#ifndef _TRIANGLE_2D_H_
#define _TRIANGLE_2D_H_

#include "Engine.h"

class Triangle2D {
public:
    Triangle2D();
    bool New(FLOAT x, FLOAT y, FLOAT width, FLOAT height, DWORD color);
    void Delete();
    void Draw();
    void Draw(FLOAT x, FLOAT y, FLOAT width, FLOAT height, DWORD color);

private:
    struct CustomVertex {
        FLOAT x, y, z, w;
        DWORD color;
    };
    static const DWORD _FVF = D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE;
    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 _vb;
};

#endif // _BOX_2D_H_
```

Triangle2D.cpp

```
#include "Triangle2D.h"

Triangle2D::Triangle2D()
: _vb(NULL)
{
}

bool Triangle2D::New(FLOAT x, FLOAT y, FLOAT width, FLOAT height, DWORD color) {

    if (FAILED(Engine::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(CustomVertex)* 4, D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY, _FVF, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &_vb, NULL)))
        return false;

    CustomVertex* vertices;
    _vb->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&vertices, 0);
    vertices[0].x = x;
    vertices[0].y = y;
    vertices[0].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[0].w = 1.0f;
    vertices[0].color = color;
    vertices[1].x = x + width;
    vertices[1].y = y;
    vertices[1].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[1].w = 1.0f;
    vertices[1].color = color;
    vertices[2].x = x;
    vertices[2].y = y + height;
    vertices[2].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[2].w = 1.0f;
    vertices[2].color = color;
    _vb->Unlock();

    return true;
}

void Triangle2D::Delete(){
    if (_vb) {
        _vb->Release();
        _vb = NULL;
    }
}

void Triangle2D::Draw() {
    Engine::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->BeginScene();
    Engine::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->SetFVF(_FVF);
    Engine::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->SetStreamSource(0, _vb, 0, sizeof(CustomVertex));
    Engine::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
    Engine::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->EndScene();
}

void Triangle2D::Draw(FLOAT x, FLOAT y, FLOAT width, FLOAT height, DWORD color) {
    CustomVertex* vertices;
    _vb->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&vertices, 0);
    vertices[0].x = x;
    vertices[0].y = y;
    vertices[0].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[0].w = 1.0f;
    vertices[0].color = color;
    vertices[1].x = x + width;
    vertices[1].y = y;
    vertices[1].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[1].w = 1.0f;
    vertices[1].color = color;
    vertices[2].x = x;
    vertices[2].y = y + height;
    vertices[2].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[2].w = 1.0f;
    vertices[2].color = color;
    _vb->Unlock();

    Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct3D does not draw "circles". It only natively draws three fundamental primitives: points, lines, and triangles. There are lots of options for how it draws those things, but that's all it can draw natively. The same is true of OpenGL (which can sometimes draw 'quads' as well, but you can always draw a quad with two triangles).

Typically drawing circles and other smooth objects is best done through "vector graphics" libraries. These can render high-quality approximations of smooth objects like circles at the correct resolution. This is what the legacy GDI library did, and what Direct2D can do. You can code your own approximation for a circle, but you probably won't do as well as Direct2D. These libraries ultimately generate points, lines, and triangles for the actual drawing operations which are performed by Direct3D.

For this reason, if you are doing 'presentation' graphics, you should look at using Direct2D instead of Direct3D. Most games actually never draw true circles. They draw 2D sprites as two textured triangles with Direct3D using an image of a circle drawn on it by an artist in something like Photoshop or Paint.

If you are insistent on using Direct3D, see the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) for Direct3D 11 [DebugDraw](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DebugDraw) helper that can draw 'rings' (i.e. line-segment circles in 3D space). This should give you an idea for how this is done. This code always uses 32 segments to form the ring, but a 'vector graphics' library would determine how many segments to break it down to based on exactly how many pixels it's going to cover on the screen:

```
void XM_CALLCONV DX::DrawRing(PrimitiveBatch<VertexPositionColor>* batch,
    FXMVECTOR origin,
    FXMVECTOR majorAxis,
    FXMVECTOR minorAxis,
    GXMVECTOR color)
{
    static const size_t c_ringSegments = 32;

    VertexPositionColor verts[c_ringSegments + 1];

    FLOAT fAngleDelta = XM_2PI / float(c_ringSegments);
    // Instead of calling cos/sin for each segment we calculate
    // the sign of the angle delta and then incrementally calculate sin
    // and cosine from then on.
    XMVECTOR cosDelta = XMVectorReplicate(cosf(fAngleDelta));
    XMVECTOR sinDelta = XMVectorReplicate(sinf(fAngleDelta));
    XMVECTOR incrementalSin = XMVectorZero();
    static const XMVECTORF32 s_initialCos =
    {
        1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f
    };
    XMVECTOR incrementalCos = s_initialCos.v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < c_ringSegments; i++)
    {
        XMVECTOR pos = XMVectorMultiplyAdd(majorAxis, incrementalCos, origin);
        pos = XMVectorMultiplyAdd(minorAxis, incrementalSin, pos);
        XMStoreFloat3(&verts[i].position, pos);
        XMStoreFloat4(&verts[i].color, color);
        // Standard formula to rotate a vector.
        XMVECTOR newCos = incrementalCos * cosDelta - incrementalSin * sinDelta;
        XMVECTOR newSin = incrementalCos * sinDelta + incrementalSin * cosDelta;
        incrementalCos = newCos;
        incrementalSin = newSin;
    }
    verts[c_ringSegments] = verts[0];

    batch->Draw(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINESTRIP, verts, c_ringSegments + 1);
}
```

> Direct3D 9 is legacy and unless you are specifically targeting Windows XP, you should be using Direct3D 11 or perhaps Direct2D if you are really doing 2D presentation graphics.

Comment: It's for a class assignment, and the professor wants us to use directx9. Am I mostly SOL in that regard then?

Comment: Then the professor wants you to figure out how to do it. It will be basically the same as the code above for arranging the vertices in a circle. The legacy DirectX SDK includes [XNAMath](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/22/xna-math-version-2-05-smoothing-the-transition-to-directxmath/) which you can use because it has the same functions as DirectXMath.